# Remove hashtag from string after typing, store it in a different string

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsstring, uilabel

I am trying to create functionality where if the user typed in a hashtag it would remove it from the textview and store it in a string. This would be triggered by typing a hashtag and hitting space after it.

What's a good way to go about this?

I figured out how to get the word out thats hash tagged. Just need a way to remove it from my display. and leave the rest of the text.

```
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(#(\\w+))"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error];
NSArray * matches = [regex matchesInString:stringCheck options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringCheck length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches ) {

    NSRange wordRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString* word = [stringCheck substringWithRange:wordRange];
    NSLog(@"%@", word);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

set `textView` delegate to your .m and .h files

`<UITextFieldDelegate>` and `[self.textField setDelegate:self];`

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string);

    if ([string isEqualToString:@" "])
    {
        NSString *stringCheck = textField.text;
        NSError *error;
        NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(#(\\w+))"
                                                                               options:0
                                                                                 error:&error];
        NSArray * matches = [regex matchesInString:stringCheck options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringCheck length])];
        for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches ) {

            NSRange wordRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
            NSString* word = [stringCheck substringWithRange:wordRange];
            NSLog(@"%@", word);

            [self.textField setText:@""];

        }

    }
    return YES;
}
```